# bootstrap form-horizontal left align

Tags: html

Can someone tell me how to align the username label to the left please.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to remove **form-horizontal**

```
<form >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> Note:if you want any text-left or right then use text-left or
>   text-right class but  your code will work fine without these classes.

read this documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

you may further use **grid-framework.less** file for your view it will manage data in row(for more controlling)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The documentation really helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could float the label to the left by adding a extra class to it and then float it via CSS.

```
 <label class="control-label col-sm-3 label" for="username">Username</label>

.label { float: left; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p0pob33d/

Comment: Better use the answers above

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an extra class to your CSS:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Then use it for your labels:

```
<label class="control-label control-label-left col-sm-3" for="username">Username</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class "form-horizontal" from the form tag. It provides the additional right align

Your html should be:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp